# Show multiple unmatched records in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. These two tables may have ID's that do not match. However, also they may have names or addresses that do not match as well. I need to be able to filter out not only ID's but first_name, last_name and street_1 from my list. I can do a JOIN on match ID's but sometimes they match but the other columns may have records that do not match which I would need to show.

> Find ID's that do not match. If they do match see if any of the other fields do not match.

Here are my expect results:

```
id  first_name_2    last_name_2 street_1                street_2
3   Teresa          White       834 Green Ridge Hill    43 Arapahoe Park
6   Rebecca         George      39157 Nelson Hill       7467 Acker Center
7   Ann             Hawkins     341 Tennessee Street    8 Bunting Street
8   Joyce           Moreno      0277 Bunker Hill Drive  6 Nancy Center
9   Kimberly        Alvarez     57332 Di Loreto Lane    0437 Waubesa Avenue
```

ID 3 & 6 is in the list because the Last Name does not match. ID 7 is last name and street_1. ID 8 & 9 ID's do not match.

Here is my sample data for reference: http://sqlfiddle.com#!9/928568/2

Comment: The SQL Fiddle uses MySQL, so I removed the SQL Server tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following: Left joining and treating nulls as blank strings. If you have a legitimate empty string, street_2 for example, it may return false positives:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    information I1
    LEFT JOIN information_2 I2 ON I1.id = I2.id
WHERE   ( I1.first_name_2 <> ifnull(I2.first_name_2, '')
      OR I1.last_name_2 <> ifnull(I2.last_name_2, '')
      OR I1.street_1 <> ifnull(I2.street_1, '')
      OR I1.street_2 <> ifnull(I2.street_2, '')
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi** I went through the sample data reference and i feel your requirement is **To find all the tuples whose exact copy is not there in there in the second table**

You can use the following **SQL** code **I tested this on your feedle and it is giving the expected result**

```
SELECT
 i.id, i.first_name_2, i.last_name_2, i.street_1, i.street_2
FROM
  information i
LEFT JOIN
information_2 i2
ON
i.id=i2.id AND i.first_name_2=i2.first_name_2 AND i.last_name_2=i2.last_name_2
AND i.street_1=i2.street_1 AND i.street_2 = i2.street_2
where
i2.id is null
```

**There is also a simple way to do this if your database supports MINUS set operator** just write

```
SELECT * FROM information
MINUS
SELECT * FROM information_2
```

and you will get the same answer